# How to select all local links in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to select all local links, regardless of if the start with

- `/path/to/page`
- `http://mydomain.com/path/to/page`
- `https://mydomain.com/path/to/page`

and replace them with

- `/#/path/to/page`

Thanks for your help.

Edit: As pointed out by dvhh in a comment, a better solution would be to target clicks. So sorry, I won't be testing solutions to mark a correct answer. Thanks for your help

Edit 2: Posted a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975818/how-to-change-the-target-of-any-local-link-when-clicked-using-javascript-jquer) about doing this via a click.

Comment: can you give us a snapshot of your HTML ?

Comment: Replacing the link might not be the right idea as you could probably do better by using the click event to test the link.

Comment: @dvhh Agreed, that would indeed be a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    if ( this.host === 'mydomain.com' || this.getAttribute('href').indexOf('/') === 0) {
        this.href = "/#" + this.pathname;
    }
});
```

It checks to see if the `href.host` matches the `domain.com` or if the first character of `href` is `/`, and if so it sets the `href` to `/#` plus the current pathname part of the `href`.

I'm using the native `getAttribute()` because I think it is safest in terms of getting the actual original attribute that was set. Perhaps it wouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

This should select all the anchor tags.

```
$("a[href*='https://mydomain.com/path/to/page'] a[href*='/path/to/page']  a[href*='http://mydomain.com/path/to/page']")
```

This should replace all the hrefs

```
$("a[href*='https://mydomain.com/path/to/page'] a[href*='/path/to/page']  a[href*='http://mydomain.com/path/to/page']").each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var currentHref = $this.attr('href');
  $this.attr("href","#/" + currentHref.substring(currentHref.indexOF("/path/to/page"), currentHref.length - 1));

})
```

Answer (score 1):

what you requested for

```
$("a").each(
    function(index,element) {
        if(element.href.indexOf("https://mydomain.com/")==0) {
            $("a").attr("href",element.href.replace("https://mydomain.com/","/#/"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pretty simple one

```
$(function () {
    $('a').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('href', '/#' + pathname);
    });
});
```